# How to get a larger map from OSM2GIS?

Tags: openstreetmap, wms

My title is more than understandable,but the explanation part is that when i try to take a part that is larger than a big city i get an explanation that is to big for "trim".I tried to get whole europe in my area but I always get a info that area which I selected is to big to cut from OSM2GIS.

Is it possible to take that kind of map/area from OSM2GIS and where can I get WMS base for that area?

I hope the rest of explanation is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a greater area, you have to use extracts by cloudemade or Geofabrik. The Osm2Gis service is not intended for large data volume.

Be prepared to download and process Gigabytes of data, which will take some time.